# LinearGradient missing parameter color after update

Tags: flutter, dart

I just updated flutter yesterday for version 1.22.0-1.0.pre and as soon as it was updated I started to get an error in the color parameter of LinearGradient:

```
Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Text(
          title,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            color:  [
              color.withOpacity(0.7),
              color,
            ],
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        ),
      ),
```

But accessing the LinearGradient classe I can see the color parameter still there:

```
class LinearGradient extends Gradient {
  /// Creates a linear gradient.
  ///
  /// The [colors] argument must not be null. If [stops] is non-null, it must
  /// have the same length as [colors].
  const LinearGradient({
    this.begin = Alignment.centerLeft,
    this.end = Alignment.centerRight,
    required List<Color> colors,
    List<double>? stops,
    this.tileMode = TileMode.clamp,
    GradientTransform? transform,
  }) : assert(begin != null),
       assert(end != null),
       assert(tileMode != null),
       super(colors: colors, stops: stops, transform: transform);
```

[image: The LinearGradient class showing that color still a parameter there.]

[image]

[image]

The only thing that I noticed in the LinearGradient class is that the required annotation doesn't have @ before it.

Anybody with the same issue? Any ideas?

Thanks for that.

Comment: What does the console say about that???

Comment: Do you get the same failure when you try to build/run the app? (i.e. Have you made sure that it's not a IntelliJ/AndroidStudio cache issue?)

Comment: change "colors" for "List" and that's it!

Comment: Run `flutter clean` and restart your IDE